# How does paymentRequest API distinguish between debit, credit and other categories cards?

Tags: google-chrome, payment-request-api

paymentRequest API [documentation](https://w3c.github.io/payment-request/) tells that a merchant can provide details to browser of what all kinds of card it supports. My question is how does browser knows the card types stored by the user and filter it.

Answer (score 3):

Let me talk about Chrome in particular. Chrome's credit card autofill storage sources from 2 places:

1. locally stored cards
2. cards stored at payments.google.com

For 2, Google server knows type of cards from their numbers. So they can be filtered. For 1, Chrome does **not** have a way to distinguish them so all available cards will be exposed without being filtered.

It may depend on implementations, but payment gateways should be able to handle card numbers gracefully without knowing their types. I've confirmed Stripe does at least.

If you do need to check the type of cards, there are online services like https://binlist.net/ which tells you meta information about a card from its first few digits.

Comment: so there is no validation for locally stored cards?

Comment: Right. Locally stored cards aren't verified on Chrome. They'll be verified at a payment gateway.